# Could a tag be added for mallet percussion?

Tags: support, feature-request

Could a tag be added for mallet percussion?  It's so different from drumset, snare, timpani, etc.  There isn't even a marimba tag, so I couldn't use that as a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

We currently have 12 questions on mallet percussion, of the 600+ percussion questions here. And the majority of those 12 use the percussion tag, as well as being easily searchable using the terms "mallet percussion" so it probably isn't something we desperately need. We do also have the 4-mallet tag

That said, if you are planning on asking more questions on this topic, I can't see any reason not to add it so I have.